# SOAP request not working in PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

We have wsdl : 
http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/XXXX_Beta_3_API/webservice.asmx?wsdl

IN PHP FILE : i have created a Class with some arrays in it..

```
class Crmtet {
   public $abc;
   public $abc2;
   public $abc3;
   public $abc4;
 }

$client = new SoapClient(http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/XXXX_Beta_3_API/webservice.asmx?wsdl);
$obj = new Crmtet();

$obj->abc= "Test";
$obj->abc2= "Test2";
$obj->abc3= "Test3";
$obj->abc4= "Test4";

$result = $client->CRM_Warehouse_Master_Insert($obj)->CRM_Warehouse_Master_InsertResult;
echo"re".$result;
```

---

But i am getting below error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was
>   unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. in
>   E:\EasyPHP-12.1\www\test\inserwarrecrm.php:60 Stack trace: #0
>   E:\EasyPHP-12.1\www\test\inserwarrecrm.php(60):
>   SoapClient->__call('CRM_Warehouse_M...', Array) #1
>   E:\EasyPHP-12.1\www\test\inserwarrecrm.php(60):
>   SoapClient->CRM_Warehouse_Master_Insert(Object(Crmtet)) #2 {main}
>   thrown in E:\EasyPHP-12.1\www\test\inserwarrecrm.php on line 60

What is the issue.. can anyone help..??

Comment: Sounds like a fault within the ASP.Net webservice. Have you spoken with the people providing the webservice for you?

Comment: yes... service is working properly.. for mobile app.. but not working on PHP.. :(

Comment: Have you debugged what is sent over the wire to see how the requests differ?